PythonのSeleniumにてChromeをシークレットモードで開いた上でプロキシを突破したい
質問内容
SeleniumでChormeをシークレットモードで開きつつプロキシを突破する方法をご教示いただけないでしょうか？
試したこと
seleniumで認証ありプロキシで接続＆ダイアログを突破してブラウザ操作する方法-python
上記記事の 「クローム(ブラウザ)に拡張機能を追加しなくてもローカルに保存してクロームオプションに追加すれば良かった。」を参考に、プロキシを突破するコードを記述した。
問題なくChromeブラウザを開くことができたのだが、シークレットモードで開こうとするとシークレットモードでブラウザは立ち上がるもののプロキシを突破できない。
記述した内容:
pluginfile = "jSONファイルとJSファイルを格納したzipファイル" #上記リンク先を参考に作成したもの
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOption()
chrome_options.add_argument('--incognito') #シークレットモード
chrome_options.add_extension(pluginfile)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get("任意のURL")

今回質問に至るまでの対応・考察

ローカルにあるファイルをadd_extensionで読み込むのではなくChromeに拡張機能として読み込むべき？
→ JSONファイルをManifest V3に対応させられず断念
add_argumentとadd_extensionは共存できない？


質問自体が古く、関連してそうな回答もそこそこ古くて承認もされていない記事ですが、もしかしたら参考になるかもしれません。How to use separate proxy settings for incognito mode under Linux?, pmarks-net/incognito-proxy
